# Android display differences between WXGA with Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Nexus 7 tablet which should have a resolution of 1280px by 800px (WXGA). I develop on Eclipse and my layout is set to display at WXGA. Then, I can place my button and object and choose their size according to what I see on the Eclipse display. The problem is that what I see in Eclipse is very different from the display on the tablet. Everything is much bigger on the tablet and it causes me a lot of troubles.

I wonder if someone have an idea about this?

***Edit***

For some reason it seems like the 7inch WSVGA is the exact replication of my Nexus 7 screen. It is strange since it offers only 964×544 pixels while the Nexus 7 should give 1280x800

Answer (score 1):

WXGA means nothing by itself. You should look at the density too. Nexus 7 is 213dpi (tvdpi) while a Galaxy Nexus is the same res but 240dpi (hdpi).

Comment: Still, If I place an object in pixel (which I know is not recommended) I should have de same result. In my case I place a button at 600px from the top and while it is not even at the bottom on Eclipse, I can't see it on the Nexus. Dpi should not change the fact that 800px are shown...

Comment: That is true. I'm not sure what could be triggering this. But really, don't use pixels :)

Comment: I tried with dp, but still I get very surprised to see that my object are always off the spot... I guess my problem come from the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to detect the screen size that the Android  device has and then run code to re-position screen elements accordingly

In Unity scripting you would get the vars Screen.Width and Screen.Height , I'm not sure what the vars are called in normal android , but you would then set your screen elements to react to what ever size the screen it .

Comment: It seems like a complicated solution for my situation. I am building this app for an onboard system using a Nexus 7... I don't need to support any other screen types.

Comment: If your sure that you don't have to support other screens, just reduce the size of the buttons , this might take a good amount of trial and error .